# CakePHP: How to use a view element inside of a controller and get html for genrate pdf using cakephp version 2.4.5

Tags: cakephp, pdf, cakephp-2.4

I am trying to get HTML from view in CakePHP and want to use it in controller to generate PDF, but when I send HTML in variable I get an error, but it's working for texts. I am calling function like this :

```
<?php

    $dataforpdf = '<h1>this is test text</h1>';


    echo $this->Html->link('Downloads PDF',  
        array('controller' =>'employers','action'=>'generatePDF',$dataforpdf )
     ); 
?>
```

My CakePHP version 2.4.5 and my controller function:-

```
public function generatePDF($id = null)
{    
    $dataforpdf  = $id;

    require('mpdf/mpdf.php');

    $mpdf=new mPDF();
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($strContent);
    $mpdf->Output('Pdf Report.pdf','D');die;
 }
```

Comment: Are you passing your HTML data in url by `GET` method?

Comment: You shouldn't really be passing HTML as a route parameter if that is what you are suggesting you are doing with `$dataforpdf`. It sounds like you are approaching this all wrong. Could you explain more what you are trying to do and update your question with more code? Also don't forget to state which version of Cake you are using!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're approaching this in a very backwards way. Your Controller should be preparing the data for a View; whereas in your code you are preparing the data in the View to pass to the Controller.

Passing HTML in the route is really not a good idea. It would be better to generate the HTML using a View template from within your controller action:-

```
public function generatePDF($id = null)
    $View = new View($this, false);
    $View->set(compact('some', 'vars'));
    $html = $View->render('view_name', 'layout_name');

    require 'mpdf/mpdf.php';
    $mpdf = new mPDF();
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
    $mpdf->Output('Pdf Report.pdf','D');
    die;
}
```

Here `view_name.ctp` would be a template containing the HTML you require for your PDF.

I'd recommend taking a look at this article on [Generating PDFs with CakePHP](http://www.dereuromark.de/2014/04/08/generating-pdfs-with-cakephp/). There also appears to be a [CakePHP 2.x plugin](https://github.com/segy/Mpdf) for the PDF library you are using which you should consider using.